# Discord.js - how to get random members and send gif photos in their profile

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i'm trying to make a system. I want the members on the server to randomly select and send every minutes the "gif" photos in their profile to the specified channel. something like a "gif-archive". I do not know how to do it.can u help ?

Comment: You need to save gifs if they send in spec channel with spec command?

Comment: not with command. I want to do it automatically

Comment: I saw this in the bot of a server. It sends the gif of the members on the server to channel randomly as my gif.

Comment: I still don’t really understand.Random member avatar?

Or rundom gif image? What must trigger this? Timing / message with some chance?

Comment: [like this image](https://img0.imguh.com/2020/01/23/Screenshot_20200123-163546_Discorde32d2e8a100d35fb.jpg)

Comment: yeah random member avatar but just gifs

Comment: I want random users to send their avatar to the channel I specify every minute. but only "gif" ones.

Answer (score 1):

Somethink like this:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  setInterval(getRandomGifAvatar, 60000, client) //Set interval for 1 minute
});

const getRandomGifAvatar = (client) => {
    const targetGuild = client.guilds.get('GUILDID') // get your guild
    const targetChannel = targetGuild.channels.get('ChannelID') // get channel 
    if(!targetGuild || !targetChannel) return

    // Get member with avatar url endswith gif
    let targetMembers = targetGuild.members.filter(member => {
        return member.user.displayAvatarURL.endsWith('gif')
    }) 
    if(targetMembers.size === 0) return

    let randUser = targetMembers.random() //get randomMember

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        setImage(randUser.user.displayAvatarURL)
    channel.send(embed)
}
```